# onblur function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: required is not a function
>       at HTMLInputElement.onblur (index.html:20)

Whenever I try to run this  HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="nbreAdultes" id="nbreAdultes" autofocus onblur= "return required(document.getElementById('nbreAdultes'));" />
```

My script:

```
function required(inputtx) {
    if (inputtx.value == "") { 
        myError.innerHTML = "Input is required";    
        return false; 
    }   
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Is the script in the <head> or at the end of <body>?

Comment: What's `myError`?

Comment: Hmmmm... renaming the function to something else like `req` does seem to work...

Comment: Most likely, `required` is some Global property.

Comment: The script is at the end of body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using inline HTML event attributes (`onblur`, `onclick`, etc), the code that is supplied as the code to run when the event occurs runs in the context of the element that triggered the event. In such cases, `required` conflicts with the HTML `required` attribute.  Using a different name for the function works as it should.

```js
function req(inputtx) {
    if (inputtx.value == "") { 
        myError.innerHTML = "Input is required";    
        return false; 
    }   
    return true; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nbreAdultes" id="nbreAdultes" autofocus onblur= "return req(document.getElementById('nbreAdultes'));" >
<span id="myError"></span>
```

To avoid this kind of issue in the future (**[and for a whole bunch of other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**), you should not be using inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`, `onsubmit`, etc.) in the first place. That is how event handlers were registered 20+ years ago. Today, we have modern standards and best practices. Use `.addEventListener()` instead and then you can call the function any valid identifier you like.

```js
// First, get a reference to the element that will fire the event
var input = document.getElementById("nbreAdultes");

// Then, register an event callback function
input.addEventListener("blur", require);

// No need to pass a reference to the element into the function.
// It will automatically be bound to "this".
// Also, no need for return true or return false.
function require() {
    if (this.value == "") { 
        myError.innerHTML = "Input is required";    
    }   
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nbreAdultes" id="nbreAdultes" autofocus>
<span id="myError"></span>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be global. Seems like it's interpreted in the scope of element when used in an event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the function name to something else, like `require()` will work:

```js
function require(inputtx) {
  console.log('Success');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nbreAdultes" id="nbreAdultes" autofocus onblur="return require(document.getElementById('nbreAdultes'));" />
```

When you use `required` as an identifier, it's interpreted as the `required` property of the element instead of the name of your function:

```html
<input type="text" onblur="console.log(required)" /> <!-- logs "false" -->
<input type="text" onblur="console.log(required)" required /> <!-- logs "true" -->
```

The reason for this is that event handlers defined as attributes execute in a different scope than normal functions. To resolve a variable `x` defined in a normal function, the runtime will first look for a local property named `x`, and if that cannot be found, it will try to find a global property of the same name.

For event handler content attributes in HTML, the scope chain is different. After trying to resolve the identifier locally (in the event handler itself), JavaScript will try to resolve it as a property of the element on which the event handler is defined. If it can't be resolved there, it will continue up the hierarchy until arriving at the global `Window` object.

So, in summary, the behavior you're witnessing occurs because your `required()` function is defined higher up the scope chain than the element's `required` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a predifined required function in HTML5 . i changed the name of the function to req and it working. Thanks to everyone who replied

Comment: No, there's no predefined `required()` function in HTML 5.