# Scope of identifiers and element properties in HTML attribute event handlers

Tags: javascript, html, scope, event-handling, dom-events

When using event handler content attributes in HTML, according to the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes), the value of `this` in the callback refers to the event's `currentTarget` property (the `input` DOM element in the example below). To access one of the DOM element's attributes, this can be done as follows:

```
<input type="text" onclick="console.log(this.type)"><!-- logs "text" -->
```

However, when writing an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48434585/3558960) to another question, I somewhat unexpectedly found out that it's possible to refer to the element's properties using their unqualified property names. The following has been tested in current versions of both Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<input type="text" onclick="console.log(type)"><!-- logs "text" -->
<input type="text" onclick="console.log(required)"><!-- logs "false" -->
<input type="text" onclick="console.log(tagName)"><!-- logs "INPUT" -->
```

Now, my question is: is this behavior specified somewhere? I don't seem to find anything in the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) or the [DOM UI events specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/), and my Google searches are also turning up empty.

Comment: http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research, I seem to have found the answer in section 17.1.6 of [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do).

It all comes down to the scope chain that is used to resolve identifiers. For a normal function defined in the global scope, when resolving an identifier `x`, the runtime will first perform a lookup in the function's local scope, and if that fails it will try to find it in the global scope.

For HTML event handler content attributes, the scope chain is different. After trying to resolve the identifier in the event handler's local scope (1), JavaScript will try to find it in the scope of the element to which the event handler is attached (2), and continue up the hierarchy (3) until it reaches the global scope (4).

```html
<form>
    <!--1--><input id="a" type="text" onclick="var x = 'y'; console.log(x)" />
    <!--2--><input id="b" type="text" onclick="console.log(type)" />
    <!--3--><input id="c" type="text" onclick="console.log(b.id)" />
    <!--4--><input id="d" type="text" onclick="console.log(location.href)" />
</form>
```

According to the aforementioned book, the composition of the scope chain was never standardized, and may be implementation-dependent.

Comment: I believe this is now part of the HTML specification as seen in [section 8.1.8.1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler). In particular, see how the `scope` argument is constructed. And from what I can tell, Chrome implements this behavior internally using `with` blocks.